# Accessing Angular services in an interchangeable way

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm pretty new to Angular. I want to show a leaderboard to my users. In order to achieve this, I created a controller and two services like so:

```
// Controller
angular.module("App.Controllers.LeaderboardController", [
    "App.Services.LeaderboardService"
])
.controller("LeaderboardController", ($scope, LeaderboardService) => {
    $scope.users = LeaderboardService.fetch();
});

// Socket Service
angular.module('App.Services.SocketService', [
    "socketio",
    "App.Services.LeaderboardService"
])
.service('SocketService', function (io, $state, LeaderboardService) {
    this.socket
    .on("connect", () => {
        console.log("Socket connected");
    })
    .on("get leaderboard data emit", (res) => {
        LeaderboardService.users = res;
    })
    .on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Socket disconnected");
    });
});

// Leaderboard Service
angular.module('App.Services.LeaderboardService', [
    "App.Services.SocketService"
])
.service('LeaderboardService', function (SocketService) {

    this.users = [];

    this.fetch = () => {
        console.log("fetching...");
        SocketService.emit("get leaderboard data");
    }
});
```

This is the flow:

1. `LeaderboardController` asks `LeaderboardService` about leaderboard information.
2. `LeaderboardService` tells `SocketService` to connect to the server and obtain leaderboard information.
3. `SocketService` calls `Leaderboard○Service` and gives it the information he needs.

However, there is a problem. Both `SocketService` and `LeaderboardService` depends on eachother so Angular complains about it.

```
Circular dependency found: SocketService <- LeaderboardService <- SocketService
```

I want to get rid of the complexity a bit. Is there any way to do the following:

```
// PSEUDO CODE
this.socket.on("get leaderboard data emit", (res) => {
     angular.resolveController("LeaderBoardController", ($scope) {
         $scope.users = res;
     });
});
```

so I can call and play with controllers myself?

It would be amazing if I can learn the best practice about doing this.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your socketio module? can you post the code or the link if it's an external script ?

Comment: Basically `this.socket` on `SocketService` refers to `io` which is basically socket.io. I only posted the relevant part for my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove your socket service and just do:

leaderBoard service :

```
angular.module('App.Services.LeaderboardService', [
    "socketio"
])
.service('LeaderboardService', function () {

    this.users = [];

    this.fetch = (scope, callback) => {

        const setUser = (res) => {
           this.users = res;
           callback(this.users);
        };

        console.log("fetching...");

        this.socket.emit("get leaderboard data");
        this.socket.on('get leaderboard data emit', setUser);

        scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
          this.socket.off('get leaderboard data emit', setUser);
        });

    }

});
```

And in your controller :

```
angular.module("App.Controllers.LeaderboardController", [
    "App.Services.LeaderboardService"
])
.controller("LeaderboardController", ($scope, LeaderboardService) => {
    LeaderboardService.fetch($scope, (users) => {
       $scope.users = users;
    });
});
```

Comment: So every time `fetch` is called an additional event handler is added to `socket`. Do you think that's a good idea?

Comment: just changed it to remove the listener on scope destroy, but didn't test it.

Comment: @Gatsbill There is no other way? I kinda want to keep socket logic on SocketService instead of adding socket.io to each controller.

Comment: For me you're doing twice the work by creating a socketService when socketio module is already a socketIO service that integrate nicely in other service where you need it. And the more independant your services are, the better it is. If you want to create a socketService then remove socketio module and create your own socket.io service

Answer (score 0):

I found my prefered solution on AngularJS's IRC channel. `icebox` helped me and solved the issue so credits goes to him.

---

The solution is having another service.

```
// Socket Service
angular.module('App.Services.SocketService', [
    "socketio",
    "App.Services.SharedDataService"
])
.service('SocketService', function (io, SharedDataService) {
    this.socket
    .on("connect", () => {
        console.log("Socket connected");
    })
    .on("get leaderboard data emit", (res) => {
        SharedDataService.data = res;
    })
    .on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Socket disconnected");
    });
});

// Socket Service
angular.module('App.Services.SharedDataService', [])
.service('SharedDataService', function () {
    this.data = [];

    this.getData = () => {
        return this.data;
    };
});
```

In controllers, we simply refer to `SharedDataService` like so:

```
angular.module("App.Controllers.LeaderboardController", [
    "App.Services.SharedDataService"
])
.controller("LeaderboardController", ($scope, SharedDataService) => {
    $scope.users = SharedDataService.getData();
});
```